# How to deal with open() returning 1

Tags: c, io, file-descriptor

I wrote a program that creates an empty text file, and prints `Succeed` if it succeeds.

Compile with `cc main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;

    // Create empty text file
    fd = open("foo.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    assert(fd != -1);

    fprintf(stderr, "File descriptor is %d\n", fd);

    printf("Succeed\n");
}
```

It works well when run with `./a.out`

When run with `./a.out >&-`, `open()` returns 1, which I understand.

But then, `printf` is writing into my file!

```
$ cat foo.txt
Succeed
```

I don't want this, so I wrote the following:

```
int main()
{
    int fd1;
    int fd2;
    int fd3;
    int fd4;

    fd1 = open("foo.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    assert(fd1 != -1);

    fd2 = open("foo.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    assert(fd2 != -1);

    fd3 = open("foo.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    assert(fd3 != -1);

    fd4 = open("foo.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    assert(fd4 != -1);

    int final_fd = fd4;
    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
    close(fd3);

    fprintf(stderr, "File descriptor is %d\n", final_fd);

    printf("Standard output\n");
}
```

It works well, `printf` will fail and return -1 but I don't care.

I know I could optimize by checking if `open()` return value is greater or equal to 3 but this is just an example.

Using `./a.out >/dev/null` works but is not a solution, I can't forbid the users of my program to close standard output.

Is this a correct way to deal with the problem?

Comment: Most programs will not work as specified if the user close stdout(or stdin or stderr) - the user has no business to do so. or the program will take charge over stdin/out/err, often by redirecting them to /dev/null from within the program. Are you sure your program is so special you need to solve this normally non-problem ?

Comment: The C standard and the POSIX standard both forbid the closing of standard input, standard output and standard error.  A C program is entitled to assume that those three streams are open.  If your users run your program with those file streams (file descriptors) closed, then all sorts of problems can occur.

Comment: I'm writing an ELF tool and I don't want it to clobber the binary file if the standard output is closed. I didn't knew it was unspecified behavior. I will either check `open()` return value or check fds 0, 1 and 2 at program startup. Indeed, `chrpath` for example does clobber my binary file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On POSIX `open` will *always* return smallest available file descriptor. The only way you can handle this is in the beginning of your program to check the file descriptors 0 ... 2 say with `isatty` - if `isatty` returns 0 *and* `errno` is set to `EBADF`, the file descriptor isn't in use, and one should then open a new descriptor from `/dev/null`:

```
for (int fd = 0; fd <= 2; fd++) {
    errno = 0;
    if (! isatty(fd) && errno == EBADF) {
        open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    }
}
```

---

Notice also that the state of those streams not being open is not standards-compliant at all. C11 7.21.3p7:

> 7 At program startup, three text streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly -- standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output). As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

This could be considered a failure in the C startup routine - in my opinion it should open those streams to `/dev/null` at least

---

Though now that I tried this, I've reached the conclusion that running programs with standard streams closed is not only brain-damaged but totally brain-dead, because any `fopen` would also open over `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr`, so I'd modify the code into:

```
struct stat statbuf;
for (int fd = 0; fd <= 2; fd++) {
    if (fstat(fd) == 0 && errno == EBADF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Id10t error: closed standard IO descriptor %d\n", fd);
        abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: *On POSIX open will always return smallest available file descriptor. The only way you can handle this is in the beginning of your program to check the file descriptors 0 ... 2 say with `isatty`*  Won't that fail if `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr` is redirected to a file? So I don't see a way to tell definitively that the standard streams are not available. I'd think I'd agree with your statement that this is a failure in the C startup routines.

Comment: @AndrewHenle *isatty* would fail, but the error wouldn't be `EBADF`. It was just the first function that came to mind with simple return values.

Comment: Doh!  Yeah, I missed that somehow.  FWIW, I haven't yet found anything in the C standard that clearly mandates the standard streams exist.

Comment: @AndrewHenle there is one even worse thing about semantics here. If the file descriptor is closed externally then even a file opened with `fopen` will open the file also for `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`. The C standard doesn't allow *that* to happen.

Comment: Using [`fstat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html) is better than `isatty()` for checking whether a file descriptor is open. The advantage is that you don't care whether standard input is a pipe, file or tty (or …); you just care whether it is open — similarly for standard output and standard error.  Using `isatty()` sends the wrong message.  If you need to know whether you can read from or write to the descriptors, you use POSIX [`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) and `F_GETFL` (rather than `F_GETFD`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler true dat, I just wanted to FGITW :D

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know it was forbidden by C standard.

Comment: @Bilow well, it is a bit more complicated... the C standard library *should* be able to handle this properly, but it doesn't